# SQL Server : getting error Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 28

Tags: sql-server

This is the error I am getting right now:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 28
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Registrat__Cours__32E0915F". The conflict occurred in database "Test2", table "dbo.Course", column 'CourseCode'.

Currently, I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    StudentID int PRIMARY KEY, 
    StudentFName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    StudentLName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    GPA float CHECK(GPA >= 0 AND GPA <= 4) 
)

CREATE TABLE Course
(
    CourseCode varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    CourseName varchar(50) UNIQUE,
    Duration int CHECK(Duration > 0)
)

CREATE TABLE Registration
(
    CourseCode varchar(10) REFERENCES Course(CourseCode), 
    StudentID int REFERENCES Student(StudentID), 
    CourseMark float CHECK(CourseMark >= 0 AND CourseMark <= 100)
    PRIMARY KEY(CourseCode, StudentID)
)

INSERT INTO Course
VALUES('ICT710', 'C#', 30)

SELECT * FROM Registration

INSERT INTO Registration
VALUES('ICT128', 123, 78.5),
      ('ICT128', 345, 68),
      ('ICT710', 123, 80)
```

How do I solve this? I am trying to add those 3 rows of data to my `Registration` table as stated in the last lines of code.

Comment: `CourseCode` column preference from `Course` table, did you add `ICT128` into course table?

Comment: Do you have row in Course table with CourceCode "ICT128" ?

Comment: you may want to look into a merge statement. a merge statement will insert the row if the pk is not there and update if it is already there.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the 'CourseCode' ICT128 into the Course table first.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Course
VALUES('ICT710', 'C#', 30)

INSERT INTO Course
VALUES('ICT128', 'PHP', 30)

SELECT * FROM Registration

INSERT INTO Registration
VALUES('ICT128', 123, 78.5),
      ('ICT128', 345, 68),
      ('ICT710', 123, 80)
```